# Can't figure out a htaccess rule

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess but can't figure out what its for.
Because of the nature of rule, searching doesn't help either.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```

Can anyone please explain what its for?

Comment: If the request part (the part of the URL after ".com") doesn't end with a `/` and it doesn't contain a "`.`", then redirect the request by appending it with a `/`. The probable intention of this rule is to handle automatic directory indexing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All this rule does is to add a trailing `/` to your URLS if there is none and if there is no `.` in the URI, so `https://example.org/test` will be redirected to `https://example.org/test/`, but `https://example.org/test.html` will not be rewritten to `https://example.org/test.html/` (but note: `https://example.org/test.case/folder` will also *not* be redirected to `https://example.org/test.case/folder/` as it contains a `.` in the URI).

```
## Do the following if the URI does not end with `/` or  does not contain an `.`: 
## the . is relevant for file names like test.html, which should n 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)

## Redirect it to the original URI with an added `/` and mark this as permanent:
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```

Comment: "`/test.case/folder` will also not be redirected" - Minor point, but if "folder" is a filesystem directory, then mod_dir will (by default) issue a 301 redirect to append a trailing slash. It's only an issue if it's `/test.case/some-other-virtual-url` that should have a trailing slash.

Answer (score 7):

Without validating, but using my experience in Apache rewriting, this configuration seems to:

1. Match on the 'path' part of the URI (not the server, port, or query parameters), for example '/my/location/file.html'.
2. Match if this part does not end on a '/' (forward-slash) character, -or- does not include a '.' (dot) character.
3. Use the full path part of the URI and append a forward-slash to it.
4. Send a HTTP 301 (permanent) redirect to direct the browser to this new URI.

This will result in the following test cases

`/ -> /
/test -> /test/
/my/resource -> /my/resource/
/my/resource.type -> /my/resource.type
/edge.case/resource -> /edge.case/resource`

So I think the rule has a purpose of adding slashes to resources that do not seem to be a file, but it seems to have an edge-case.

If not adding a slash to a resource with '.' (dot) character in the non-file part of the path the regular expression should be changed to:

```
# match paths which do not end with a slash, or do not resemble a file with an extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.[^/]+$)
# redirect permanently to the same uri with a slash
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```

Comment: `!(\/$|\.[^\/]*)` - Your updated regex is really no different. You need an end-of-string anchor on the 2nd part (that matches the extension) as well. Perhaps something like: `!(/|\.[a-zA-Z]+)$` (no need to escape the slashes).

Comment: @MrWhite Good catch! I updated my answer!